# In Angular 8 I want to be able to stop a nativeElement from scrolling on mouse leave

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll, angular8

I'm using Angular 8 with typescript.

When I mouse over the div below it scrolls, which works.
When I mouse leave the parent div it needs to stop scrolling at the point of scroll its at.

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="container-scroll-area" #scrollMe>
</div>

<div class="scroller-down" (mouseleave)="onMouseLeave($event)">

  <div class="scrollBKWS" (mouseover)="scroll()"></div>

</div>
```

**My TS:**

```
  @ViewChild('scrollMe', { static: false }) private scrollMe: ElementRef;

  public scroll(): void {
    const scrollContainer = thi.scrollMe.nativeElement;
    scrollContainer.scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollHeight;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event']) public onMouseLeave(event: any): void { 
    console.log('mouseleave');
    console.log(event);
    console.log(this.scrollMe.nativeElement);

    // event.stopPropagation();
    // event.preventDefault();
  }
```

I've tried host listener, which it hits but cant seem to get the native element to stop scrolling.

Comment: your question is a little vague, besides the errors in your snippet I don't see what you want to do, setting scrollTop scrolls instantly as far as I know so what do you want to happen on leave? as it wouldn't be "scrolling" anymore

Comment: Your question is not clear can you provide simple stackblitz example, please?

Comment: I want to mouseover a div to scroll down smoothly to the bottom of a div, and then when I leave the div using mouseleave I need it to stop exactly where it is in the scrolling, before it hits the bottom of the div its scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the nativeelement by using the event.currentTarget this is same as what you have get as nativeElement.
so your code will look like

```
 @ViewChild('scrollMe', { static: false }) private scrollMe: ElementRef;

  public scroll(): void {
    const scrollContainer = thi.scrollMe.nativeElement;
    scrollContainer.scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollHeight;
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event']) public onMouseLeave(event: any): void { 
    console.log('mouseleave');
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
  }
```